# Is there any buildin keywords or function to check nesting of header tags?

Tags: robotframework

Is there any keyword or function available in robot framework where I can check the nesting of header tags are proper or not. Like H2 tag should always comes below H1 tag. H3 tag should not directly come under H1 by skipping H2 tag. LIkewise.

Expecting the code or some workaround like getting all page source and using some string manupalation technique if we can check line by line and verify.

Comment: I presume your question is to check a structure like `<h1></h1><div><span><h2></h2></span></div>`, not `<h1><h2></h2></h1>`, right? The latter though semanticly correct is not something that's widely used. Be more specific, add a sample of the HTML. Also - add what have you tried so far, in the current form the question looks like an assignment, not an ask - not the way SO works.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `for` loop from `1` to the desired maxium depth of nested header tags. For example: from `1` to `5` if `h5` is the last header.

In the loop iterate through all type of header elements and get their child elements. You could use the `Get WebElements` keyword from the SeleniumLibrary with an xpath like this:

```
${children}=    Get WebElements    //h${i}/*    # ${i} is the variable that is incremented in the loop
```

or if you want to check indirect children:

```
${children}=    Get WebElements    //h${i}//*
```

Iterate through `${children}` and check the tags, if one is invalid, handle it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I need some more information on it. As my requirement is to check the herarchy is followed or not. Like H1-h2-h3. That is why i was looking for string function where I can read the code line by line and if on one line I found h1 then under that line there should be h2 not h3.